# How to pass data between pages in Ionic app

Tags: html, angularjs, variables, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have had a look at all the examples around and tried to integrate with my Ionic project and failed. Here is what I have so far.

I am using a project created using creator.ionic.com

I have an html page that im loading a JSON file into

```
(agentSchedule.html)

<ion-view style="" title="Agent Schedule">
 <ion-content class="has-header" overflow-scroll="true" padding="true">
  <ion-refresher on-refresh="doRefresh()">
    </ion-refresher>
    <div ng-controller="agentScheduleCtrl">
      <ion-list style="">
          <ion-item  class="item-icon-right item item-text-wrap item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="user in users">
            <img ng-src="{{ user.image }}">
          <h2>{{ user.fname }} {{ user.lname }}</h2>
          <h4>Role : {{ user.jobtitle }}</h4>
          <h4>Username : {{ user.username }}</h4><i class="button-icon icon ion-ios-arrow-forward"></i>
          </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Here is the controller and routes for that page

```
.controller('agentScheduleCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
  var url = "http://www.otago.ac.nz/itssd-schedule/mobileappdevice/services/getUsers.php";
  var url = "users.json";
  $http.get(url).success( function(response) {
      $scope.users = response;
});

.state('menu.agentSchedule', {
  url: '/page4',
  views: {
  'side-menu21': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/agentSchedule.html',
    controller: 'agentScheduleCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

I am another page that I want to pass the username to, and then use on any page  that I go from there

```
(specificAgentDetails.html)

<ion-view style="" view-title="Agent Specific Schedule">
<ion-content class="has-header" overflow-scroll="true" padding="true">

</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here is the controller and routes for that page

```
.controller('specificAgentDetailsCtrl', function($scope) {

})

.state('menu.specificAgentDetailsCtrl', {
url: '/page9',
views: {
  'side-menu21': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/specificAgentDetailsCtrl.html',
    controller: 'specificAgentDetailsCtrl'
  }
}
})
```

How to Pass the user.username JSON variable to the next page as a global variable ??

Any help would be awesome - im going around in circles

Comment: Angular is an SPA framework. You're supposed to have 1 (!!!) .html page and switch views in it, not several .html pages.

Comment: New to Ionic, that's how the creator.ionic.com made it, so I'm just following along - any ideas using the format that I've used ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what @shershen said is true most ionic apps are set up as SPA's, what you're going to do isn't a "ionic" thing it's more of a AngularJS thing. You're going to want to setup a Service to hold your User info and then share it with your other controllers.

1. Create a Factory to share the data.
2. Inject the factory into the first controller and set it.
3. Inject the factory into the second controller and retrieve it.

[Share data between AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)

If you're familiar with get/set in OOP you should have no problem.

```
.factory('Data', function () {
var user = {};
return {
    getUser: function () {
        return user;
    },
    setUser: function (userparameter) {
        user = userparameter;
    }
};
})
.controller('agentScheduleCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout, Data) {
 var url = "http://www.otago.ac.nz/itssdschedule/mobileappdevice/services/getUsers.php";
 var url = "users.json";
$http.get(url).success( function(response) {
  Data.setUser(response);
  $scope.users = response;
});
```

Then in your second controller:

```
.controller('specificAgentDetailsCtrl', function($scope, Data) {
   $scope.user = Data.getUser();
})
```

Make sure the syntax between the view and controllers are correct. I'm using user you're using users, setup breakpoints in your controllers to see what's going on there.

Comment: Good man - I'll try it out,. hopefully I can get my head around it

Comment: OK got it working within the same page, how do I pass the variable to another page ??

Comment: Not page. Think Controller. You want to pass data between controllers. In actually they're states, the concept of pages isn't relevant to your project because if you notice you're routing to views. Now in your second controller inject the shared factory and then get the user object.

Comment: The link above illustrates how to inject the shared data service and then get the values you've stored.

Comment: so if a <h4> had the variable of {{user.username}} in it how would i use that data into the factory ?? as of code at start. - do i need a function to start the transfer ?

Answer (score 0):

I use a little generic factory to do the job.

```
.factory('LocalRepo', function () {
    var data = {}
    return {
        Get: function (key) {
            return data.key;
        },
        Set: function (key, val) {
            return data.key = val;
        }
    }
})

.controller('One', function($scope, LocalRepo) {
    //Set in first controller
    //TODO: $scope.users = .... from your call
    LocalRepo.Set('users', $scope.users);
})

.controller('Two', function($scope, LocalRepo) {
    //Get in second controller
    $scope.users = LocalRepo.Get('users');
})
```

Use it to set whatever you want between controllers

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quite simple solution. use `$window` and it will hold the data globally available for all controllers, services or anything etc.

```
.controller('agentScheduleCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout,$windows) {
    $window.users = [];
    var url = "http://www.otago.ac.nz/itssd-schedule/mobileappdevice/services/getUsers.php";
    var url = "users.json";
    $http.get(url).success( function(response) {
        $window.users = response;
    });
})
```

Inject `$window` as dependency in other controller and you can access it like `$window.users`.

Hope  it helps someone.